# Inheritance C++ issue when assigning base class to sub class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators, operator-overloading

This may be a silly question about inheritance, but it does not make much sense on why I am not allowed to do this. The base class I am inheriting from is `std::string`:

```
class A : public std::string
```

When I use `class A`, I want to do this:

```
A text;
std::string str = "hello";
text = str;
```

The compiler complains that there is no binary operator `=` to do this.

The reason I want to inherit from string is to add some extra functionality but not lost the functionality `std::string` gives by default.

Is there a reason why a base class cannot be automatically assigned to a sub class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot inherit assignment operators, they are given special treatment. You can use `using` to bring them up from the base class.

Also, it's horrendously bad to inherit from Standard-provided classes, except iostream.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the answers. I'll switch over to using a normal member std::string variable then.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a reason why a base class cannot be automatically assigned to a sub class?

Yes. It is because the base class *is not a* subclass. You can only assign the other way around: assigning a subclass instance to a base class instance would be fine since the subclass is-a base class.

This is the general rule; the other answer explains what's specifically wrong in case of  `std::string`.